# How to update the variable in TextArea(Jframe) in every 2 sec?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, jsoup

*---This project aims to update the a list of stock quotes that parsed from website by `Jsoup` in every 2 sec.*

---

Procedure :

1. Extracting list of price quote using JSOUP ( this has been done and stored in String variable (`Stock`) (done)
2. Creating a Jframe ,JPanel ,TextArea .Paste the `Stock` on the TextArea . Hence , the stockquote can be shown on Jframe-textArea. (done)
3. Make the TextArea update the variable `stock` in every 2 sec (doing)

---

Code:

```
    public void run() {     // Just conduct the Parsing 

    try {
        Parsing();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Stock2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

---

```
     public  void Parsing() throws Exception 

    {
    }//Jsoup code .Parsing the element from website and stored in String `Stock`
```

---

Main Code working here :main method

In main , create Jframe ,panel ,textarea here . Then , paste the `stock` on JLabel .

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
//  Timer timer = new Timer();
//timer.schedule(new Stock2(), 2000, 2000); 


// javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
//        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


Stock2 stock3=new Stock2();
stock3.run();

    final  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stock");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            ///------------------------------

            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                  frame.setVisible(true);
             ///------------------------------

          final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                 ///------------------------------



      JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(25,40);
         ///------------------------------
     JScrollPane scroll= new JScrollPane(textArea);

scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
         ///------------------------------
                textArea.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16));
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setOpaque(false);
    textArea.setEditable(false   );
      //  textArea. append("g"); 
      textArea.setSize( textArea.getPreferredSize() );
    textArea.setText(String.valueOf(stock));
      //textArea. insert("               ", 5);
       //    textArea.setTabSize(50);
             ///------------------------------

        frame.add(panel);
     panel.add(scroll);
   //  frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
    //    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

**After search , i know that i should use `Swing Timer` .But i dun know where to put on (main ? run?). Also , i try to work on and add to the main method .But error occurs .How to solve ?  **

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels i tried to replace ur code instead of my code .But some errors occur .(maybe the first two method is not fitting . still need some modifications )

Comment: Mon -- never borrow our code -- borrow ideas and write your own code.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels  Hey Sir , i m a rookie toward JAVA . I have worked for a long time for the code .I still cant make the event driven successful . As last time i didn't show the  public  void Parsing() , you could not work out for the Parsing(). Would you like to help me combine with the whole code or make some insights

Answer (score 3):

You want to do a task every 2 seconds, and so a Swing Timer would seem to be the way to do this, but since the task involves querying the contents of the internet, this process takes more than a trivial amount of time, something which could potentially freeze your GUI if run on the GUI event thread as a Swing Timer would do. Instead you should probably use a SwingWorker, and inside of the SwingWorker use a [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), not a Swing Timer since you'll be off the Swing event thread, to repeatedly call the code to obtain the data that you need, and then pass the information to the GUI using the SwingWorker's publish/process method pair. Check out the tutorial, [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the details on how to do this, and in fact, you would likely create a `SwingWorker<Void, String>` so that publish/process would know that it is text data that you wish to transmit.

Another unrelated issue is that you've got way too much code, and too much GUI code in the static main method, and if this isn't refactored, you're going to have a program that is very difficult to debug, to test and to maintain. Fix this by creating separate classes for each responsibility.

Other issues:

- **Never** set the preferred size of a JTextArea. Do this and see what happens when your text eventually fills the visible text area. Then add some more text, and the JScrollPane won't scroll since you've fixed the text area's pref size. Instead set it's column and row properties.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class StockEg {

    // main method starts Swing event thread and 
    // calls create and show
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    // create pertinent classes and start them running. that's it
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // create and display GUI
        StockGui stockGui = new StockGui();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StockEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(stockGui.getMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // create worker and hook up with GUI
        MyWorker myWorker = new MyWorker(stockGui);
        myWorker.execute();  // start worker
    }
}
```

```
// gui class
class StockGui {
    private static final int TA_ROWS = 20;
    private static final int TA_COLS = 40;
    private static final Font TA_FONT = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 16);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    public StockGui() {
        textArea.setFont(TA_FONT);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        mainPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    // get main JPanel that holds everything
    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    // allow outside classes to add text to JTextArea
    public void appendText(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
    }
}
```

```
// SwingWorker to run long-running process
class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    private static final long PERIOD = 2000; // for timer
    private StockGui stockGui; // gui reference

    // non-GUI class that parses web page
    private MyJSoupParser myJSoupParser = new MyJSoupParser();

    public MyWorker(StockGui stockGui) {
        this.stockGui = stockGui;  // hook up gui reference
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // create java.util.Timer
        java.util.Timer myTimer = new java.util.Timer(true);
        // start timer with task
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, PERIOD);
        return null;
    }

    // method to send text to the GUI
    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String chunk : chunks) {
            stockGui.appendText(chunk + "\n");
        }
    }

    // timer task that extracts text from the JSoup parser
    // and then calls publish to send text to process method and GUI
    private class MyTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String parsedText = myJSoupParser.getText();
            publish(parsedText);
        }
    }
}
```

```
// dummy class just for demo purposes
class MyJSoupParser {
    private int dummyCounter = 0;
    public String getText() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        return "Parsed Text: " + dummyCounter++;
    }
}
```